# Could not load icon plyer library

Tags: python, python-3.x, notifications

I have a little problem with Plyer library, I'm trying to custom a notification's appereance but evrything is okay until I try to replace the default icon of the notification, here's my code:

```
from plyer import notification
notification.notify(title='Managen', message='Notification',app_icon = r'C:\Users\Santiago\Pictures\icon.ico',timeout = 10)
```

This is the output:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Santiago\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Santiago\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Santiago\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\plyer\platforms\win\libs\balloontip.py", line 208, in balloon_tip
    WindowsBalloonTip(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Santiago\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\plyer\platforms\win\libs\balloontip.py", line 132, in __init__
    raise Exception('Could not load icon {}'.format(app_icon))
Exception: Could not load icon C:\Users\Santiago\Pictures\icon.ico
```

I don't know what is exactly happening, if you could help me it'd be great, beforehand thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Download the icon in **.ico** format, I was having the same problem when I downloaded in the **.png** format and then changed extension to **.ico**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your icon is not in the path:

```
C:\Users\Santiago\Pictures\
```

or its name is different.
Just double check.

I get the same Exception if I move the file or rename it, but
the notification icon shows when I have icon.ico in the same dir as the .py file and I use your code like that:

```
notification.notify(title='Managen', message='Notification', app_icon = r'icon.ico', timeout = 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just name the icon file as "icon" only. it recognise it as icon.ico.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

Your location looks like this: `C:\Users\Santiago\Pictures\`

Simply change it to this: `C:/Users/Santiago/Pictures/`

Answer (score 0):

Just download a proper .ico image just by changing the extension it will work in your system but while compiling it won't work other than that you can write any name for the image but the extension of the image must be .ico

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).